# after creating an inheritance it outputs NULL value

Tags: php, oop, inheritance

I want to have my inheritance but it outputs null. it was working but when I extends Patient to clinic it starts to output null. my teachers instruction was to have inheritance and I need help im still studying about this inheritance but its kind a complicated for me.

```
<?php
    class Patient{
    
        private $name;
        private $age;
        private $gender;
    
        public function record($name, $age, $gender){
            $this->name = $name;
            $this->age = $age;
            $this->gender = $gender;
        }   
    
        public function getName(){
            return $this->name;
        }
    
        public function getAge(){
            return $this->age;
        }
    
        public function getGender(){
            return $this->gender;
        }
    
    }
    
    class Clinic extends Patient{
    
        private $patients = [];
    
        public function getPatients(){
            return $this->patients;
        }
    
        public function assignPatient($name, $age, $gender){
            $this->patients[] = new Patient($name, $age, $gender);
        }
    
        public function deletePatient($index){
            unset($this->patients[$index]);
        }
    
    }
    
    $clinic = new Clinic();
    
    $clinic->assignPatient("Patrick star",18,"Male");
    $clinic->assignPatient("SpongeBob Squarepants",17,"Male");
    $clinic->assignPatient("Eugene Krab",28,"Male");
    
    $clinic->deletePatient(1);
    
    var_dump($clinic->getPatients());
```

Comment: You defined `public function record(...)` to create a new Patient, not the constructor

Comment: even if i change the 'public function record(...)' into __contructor it still output null

Comment: If you haven't already, enable error reporting/display ([How do I get PHP errors to display?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display?rq=1)). You'd get an `Uncaught ArgumentCountError` when changing `record()` to `__construct()` since `new Clinic();` wouldn't supply any parameters. Keep `record()` and add new patients via that method

Comment: Also not really sure why you'd need/want inheritance here, since Clinic and Patient don't really share common attributes. That code would also work if you didn't `extends Patient`

Comment: i didnt have any errors but the problem is that it outputs null value.. did online compiler aren't automatically enable error reporting/display?

Comment: "_did online compiler aren't automatically enable error reporting/display?_" We have no idea which online compiler you used. _Usually_ they do enable error reporting. With the code you posted you get NULL because you don't use `record()` to add patients

Comment: "_my teachers instruction was to have inheritance_" Inheritance here would make sense if you had a class Person and class Patient and class Doctor would extend the Person class.

Answer (score 0):

A few things to change here. First, you called the function for a new patient `record`, but you use `new Patient()`. Rename the function to `__construct` to make it the class constructor. Now you can use `new Patient(...)`.

Also, I think extending `Patient` in `Clinic` doesn't really make sense here, because you don't want to use the classes provided by `Patient` and extend them.

So remove `extends Patient` and your code should work now:

```php
<?php
class Patient{
    
    private $name;
    private $age;
    private $gender;

    public function __construct($name, $age, $gender){
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->age = $age;
        $this->gender = $gender;
    }   

    public function getName(){
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function getAge(){
        return $this->age;
    }

    public function getGender(){
        return $this->gender;
    }
    
}
    
class Clinic {

    private $patients = [];

    public function getPatients(){
        return $this->patients;
    }

    public function assignPatient($name, $age, $gender){
        $this->patients[] = new Patient($name, $age, $gender);
    }

    public function deletePatient($index){
        unset($this->patients[$index]);
    }

}

$clinic = new Clinic();

$clinic->assignPatient("Patrick star",18,"Male");
$clinic->assignPatient("SpongeBob Squarepants",17,"Male");
$clinic->assignPatient("Eugene Krab",28,"Male");

$clinic->deletePatient(1);

print_r($clinic->getPatients());
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Patient Object
        (
            [name:Patient:private] => Patrick star
            [age:Patient:private] => 18
            [gender:Patient:private] => Male
        )

    [2] => Patient Object
        (
            [name:Patient:private] => Eugene Krab
            [age:Patient:private] => 28
            [gender:Patient:private] => Male
        )

)
```

*Tested on PHP 7.4 and PHP 8.0*

Comment: *my teachers instruction was to have inheritance* so I think inheritance is needed in some form or another.  So just removing it may be right in this case, it's not what OP needs.

Comment: But with `extends` you extend it - so you have all your functions from the other (in your case `Patiend`) class in your `Clinic` class. You don't need and don't want that, because `Clinic` is a totally different class. Extending `Patient` would make sense if you have another type of a patient which uses the normal `Patient` functions but also needs a few new. You don't need `extends` in your case, it simply doesn't make sense and won't work.

Comment: My comment was about that it sounds like they **need** to use inheritance, not about if it was correct or not in this case.  I don't know the actual assignment, so I can't comment on how it could be used in a correct manner.